# Cant change Textview with Handler

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void run() {
int ret = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[16384]; //ByteArray
int i;
while (ret >= 0) {
    try {
        ret = mInputStream.read(buffer);   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        break;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < ret) {
        int len = ret - i;
       if(len >=1){
           Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler);
           int value = (int) buffer[i];
           m.obj = new ValueMsg(value);
           mHandler.sendMessage(m);
```

Here i think i send byte for byte from buffer to mHandler. It´s possible to send the total value? Or is the like Bluetooth byte for byte?
           }
1

```
    }

};

Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg)msg.obj;                
        mTextView.setText(""+t.getReading()+" Value");
        }
```

};
It does not change the textView i dont understand why.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
super.onDestroy();
}
public class ValueMsg{
private int reading;

public ValueMsg(int reading){
    this.reading = reading;
}
public int getReading(){
    return reading;
}
```

Is it always necessarily to write a new class to for the value?

And the last question can you advise me a good book for android and java or a youtube site?:)

**EDIT**:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage( Message msg){
             post (new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg) msg.obj;
                    mTextView.setText(" Value");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg)msg.obj;                
        mTextView.setText(""+t.getReading()+" Value");
```

to

```
 post(new Runnable() {
void run() {
 ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg)msg.obj;                
            mTextView.setText(""+t.getReading()+" Value");
});
```

use your handler to post the change to the UI thread

Comment: Sorry I forgot the handler:D